# Возможно ли A-GPS переключить на GPS?

Tags: телефония

GPS определяет координаты по спутнику и бесплатно. A-GPS -по вышкам оператора и это платно по трафику, особенно если пакет на мало мегабайт. У меня вопрос, если на телефоне написано a-gps, возможно ли отключить эту функцию и использовать gps, не платя за трафик или a-gps сама по себе, а gps в телефонах может не быть?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего нет, т.к. это разные вещи.A-GPS нужен 3G без него он не работает + ему реально нужен трафик для работы, но определяет он местоположение быстро, но погрешность больше чем при приемнике GPS.

GPS не нужен инет для определения, у него есть спутники, но он нагружает своими расчетами процессор на мобильном устройстве.

1.A-GPS сводит к минимуму время с момента включения GPS-приемника до первой выдачи координат.2. A-GPS более правильно и быстро может просчитать координаты, если допустим GPS сейчас работает только с одним спутником, а у A-GPS есть возможность обратиться к соседним станциям и по времени отдачи инфы от них получить местонахождение.

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве телефонов есть и то, и то. И есть возможность отключать ненужную в данный момент времени технологию.![alt text][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X4zZ.jpg

Comment: У меня на планшете тоже обе присутствуют.